# What does got.extend do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, middleware, node.js-got

What does `got.extend` do and is there an equivalent function by undici?

I have tried reading the npm documentation in gitHub but am unsure on what `got.extend`  does?

I have the following code, which I would like to write using undici

```
function initializeClient(clientName) {

  log.info('Begin Initializing REST for %s', clientName);

  const config = rest[clientName]; // eslint-disable-line security/detect-object-injection

  // @ts-ignore

  const client = got.extend(config.base);

  clients[clientName] = client; // eslint-disable-line security/detect-object-injection

  log.info('REST Initialization Complete for %s : %j', clientName, Object.keys(client));

  return client;

}

module.exports.initializeClient = initializeClient;
```

I have tried `undici.fetch` but that gives

```
TypeError: Failed to parse URL from [object Object]
```

Comment: It seems to be documented at https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/blob/main/documentation/lets-make-a-plugin.md. As for what it does, you can easily [read the source](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/blob/5cbcf526b6e7be5e40f1ad137172d7b2b68988da/source/create.ts#L106-L133) yourself.

Comment: Their [documentation](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/blob/215e06a499/documentation/10-instances.md#gotextendoptions-instances) says _"Configure a new `got` instance with merged default options. The options are merged with the parent instance's `defaults.options` using `options.merge(…)`."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const instance = got.extend({
  option1 : value1,
  option2 : value2,
  option3 : value3,
})
const response1 = await instance(URL1);
const response2 = await instance(URL2);
```

is equivalent to:

```
const response1 = await got(URL1, {
  option1 : value1,
  option2 : value2,
  option3 : value3,  
});
const response2 = await got(URL2, {
  option1 : value1,
  option2 : value2,
  option3 : value3,  
})
```

So if you need to use the same options for each request you make, you can create an instance that has those options set as defaults (so you don't have to pass them each time).

It doesn't look like `undici` has something similar.